# Handling text works in Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, text

I make a little website with images and TTS when you click on each image.
This is ment for persons with an Intellectual Disability.
In Firefox, everything is ok but not in Chrome. In Chrome I hear no speech. It seems the problem is in "fnHandleText". I tested everything, searched everywhere but no solution yet. Do you see a problem?

```js
var i;
var SpeechList = document.getElementsByClassName("speech");

function voiceEndCallback() {
  for (i = 0; i < SpeechList.length; i++) {
    if (SpeechList[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("isplaying") > -1) {
      SpeechList[i].setAttribute("class", "speech afterplay");
    }
  }
}
var fnSpeech = function() {
  responsiveVoice.speak(this.innerHTML, 'Dutch Female');
  this.setAttribute("class", "speech isplaying");
  event.preventDefault();
};
for (i = 0; i < SpeechList.length; i++) {
  SpeechList[i].setAttribute("class", "speech beforeplay");
  SpeechList[i].addEventListener("click", fnSpeech, false);
}

function fnHandleText(FileText) {
  var TextArray = FileText.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < TextArray.length - 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = TextArray[i];
  }
}
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    fnHandleText(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", TextFileName, true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var TextFileName = "../../test/text.txt";
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../sp_css/lees.css">

<div class="unselectable">
  <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-8">
    <div id="row-1" class="w3-row w3-container">
      <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container"><img src="../../test/1.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 speech" id="zin1" style="width:100%"></div>
      <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container"><img src="../../test/2.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 speech" id="zin2" style="width:100%"></div>
      <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container"><img src="../../test/3.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 speech" id="zin3" style="width:100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-2" class="w3-row w3-container">
      <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container"><img src="../../test/4.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 speech" id="zin4" style="width:100%"></div>
      <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container"><img src="../../test/5.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 speech" id="zin5" style="width:100%"></div>
      <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container"><img src="../../test/6.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 speech" id="zin6" style="width:100%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
```

EDIT: When I use console.log:
`function fnHandleText(FileText)` does his job but innerhtml in  `var fnSpeech = function () { responsiveVoice.speak(this.innerHTML, 'Dutch Female');};` doesn't. It's empty.

Edit2: I found no solution yet but now I know handling text is not the problem, I asked a new question here:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848682/text-to-speech-difference-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: @Jon Uleis Hi Jon. You added a snippet. I think this code can't function like this in a snippet... I didn't provide images, text and css.

Comment: Correct - it was just for organization. Disabled the snippet functionality...

Comment: @Jon Uleis Thanx, Do you have an idea of the problem here?

Comment: Is it Microphone/Audio options are accepted in Chrome ?

Comment: The speech works with the Responsivevoice script. No audio is recorded.