# Text to speech difference in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, text-to-speech, innerhtml

This is code for a little website with images and TTS.
When you click on the number 1, 2 and 3 you should hear a dutch voice and also when you click on the 3 images with a '?'.
In Firefox, everything is ok. I hear 6 different numbers but not in Chrome.
In Chrome I hear 1, 2, and 3 but the 4, 5 and 6 under the images don't work.
As you can see in the code, the only difference is the image added.
I keep the scripts at the bottom so the images can load first.
I am searching for hours (days) but no result.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var TextFileName = "../../sp_uploader/dagprogramma/test.txt";
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">

    <div class="w3-card"><span class="speech" id="zin1"></span></div>
    <div class="w3-card"><span class="speech" id="zin2"></span></div>
    <div class="w3-card"><span class="speech" id="zin3"></span></div>

    <div class="w3-card"><img src="../../sp_uploader/dagprogramma/leeg.jpg" class="speech" id="zin4"></div>
    <div class="w3-card"><img src="../../sp_uploader/dagprogramma/leeg.jpg" class="speech" id="zin5"></div>
    <div class="w3-card"><img src="../../sp_uploader/dagprogramma/leeg.jpg" class="speech" id="zin6"></div>

    <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
    <script src="../../sp_js/leesfotoboek.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here the script:

```
    var i;
var SpeechList = document.getElementsByClassName("speech");
var fnSpeech = function () {
    console.log(this.innerHTML, " = innerhtml !!!");
        responsiveVoice.speak(this.innerHTML, 'Dutch Female');
};
for (i = 0; i < SpeechList.length; i++) {
    SpeechList[i].addEventListener("click", fnSpeech, false);
}
function fnHandleText(FileText) {
    var TextArray = FileText.split(",");
    console.log(TextArray);
    for (var i = 0; i < TextArray.length-1; i++) {
        document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = TextArray[i];
        console.log(document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = TextArray[i]);
    }
}
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        fnHandleText(this.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", TextFileName, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially an img element should not have child elements/html, so the behavior when you modify the innerHTML is undefined.

Instead of adding innerHTML to your elements, you could try adding a data attribute to each:

```
var fnSpeech = function () {
    responsiveVoice.speak(this.getAttribute('data-speech-text'), 'Dutch Female');
};

for (i = 0; i < SpeechList.length; i++) {
    SpeechList[i].addEventListener("click", fnSpeech, false);
}

function fnHandleText(FileText) {
    var TextArray = FileText.split(",");
    console.log(TextArray);
    for (var i = 0; i < TextArray.length; i++) {
        // Set the text for non-img elements
        document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = i + 1
        document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).setAttribute('data-speech-text', TextArray[i]);
    }
}
```

---

I made a couple edits to make my suggested code more compatible with yours

---

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gupb8xwL/7/) to show the functionality

Comment: Sorry about that, I overlooked that you still need the text within your span elements. I will edit my answer. Also: your for loop condition should be i < TextArray.length. If you subtract 1 you will skip the last element.

Comment: I also edited my answer so that the order of declarations is correct, as running the for-loop before giving the definition of fnSpeech would result in nothing happening on click events.

Comment: I didn't take a super deep look at your code, but if the OP is associating text to the images, you might as well use the `alt` attribute instead of `data-speech-text` and kill two birds with one accessibility stone.

Comment: @backnext What?  What I'm saying is instead of setting `data-speech-text` in the `get/setAttribute(...)` calls, use `alt`.

Comment: @MichaelHorn Thanks a lot. This seems to be what I needed. Now can I still use the html code like this for the images? '<div class="w3-card"><img src="../../sp_uploader/dagprogramma/leeg.jpg" class="speech" id="zin4"></div>'

Comment: @zero298 That would work for the images, but using a data attribute works for span as well as img, so there need not be special code for different tags.

Comment: @backnext Glad I could help! And I don't see anything wrong with that code... Does it work as expected?

Comment: @zero298 It works with alt, didn't expect this... So I replaced 'document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).setAttribute('data-speech-text', TextArray[i]);' with ' document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).alt = TextArray[i];' and 'responsiveVoice.speak(this.getAttribute('data-speech-text')' with 'responsiveVoice.speak(this.alt,' Should this be faster than set and getAttribute?

Comment: @MichaelHorn Yes I will sleep better now.

Comment: @backnext Neither is faster.  It's just that `alt` helps with screen readers on `<img>` but as Michael said, only img have `alt` so `data-*` has better availability.

Comment: @zero298 ok so I'll use the set and getAttribute. Thanx for help.

Comment: @MichaelHorn I just want to notice I replaced 'document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = i + 1' by 'document.getElementById("zin" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = TextArray[i];' because I use a textfile to get the text.